# Use dynamically typed object implementing `tokio::io::AsyncWrite`

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am pretty new to Rust so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

This code works fine:

```rust
pub fn say_hello() {
    let fut = tokio::io::write_all(tokio::io::stdout, "Hello, world!").then(|_| {});
    tokio::run(fut);
}
```

Whereas the following code fails to compile:

```rust
pub fn say_hello(w: Box<dyn tokio::io::AsyncWrite>) {
    let fut = tokio::io::write_all(w, "Hello, world!").then(|_| {});
    tokio::run(fut);
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
error[E0277]: `dyn tokio_io::async_write::AsyncWrite` cannot be sent between threads safely
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I want (actually dispatching dynamically, not just making the function generic).

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** `tokio::run` `expects` Future that implements `Send` and also in `'static` life time.

If you add required restrictions to your parameter it will work same as `Stdout` :

```rust
pub fn say_hello(w: Box<dyn tokio::io::AsyncWrite + Send + 'static>) {
    let fut = tokio::io::write_all(w, "Hello, world!").then(|_| Ok(()));

    tokio::run(fut);
}
```

**Note :** 
`Stdout` works because [Stdout implementations](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.22/tokio/io/struct.Stdout.html#implementations)  already contain `Send`, and it is an owned data for the enclosing scope.

---

**But how Rust is able to know the `Future` that created by `write_all` is `Send` or not ?**

Calling `write_all` with an implementation of `AsyncWrite` is fine, since [tokio::io::write_all](https://docs.rs/tokio-io/0.1.12/tokio_io/io/fn.write_all.html) expects implementation of `AsyncWrite`. But [tokio::run](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.22/tokio/runtime/fn.run.html) expects an **owned** or `'static` `Future` which implements `Send`

You are trying to run the `WriteAll` future, but please check this `Send` [implementation](https://docs.rs/tokio-io/0.1.12/tokio_io/io/struct.WriteAll.html#synthetic-implementations) on `WriteAll`, it only implements `Send` when `T` and `A` implements `Send`. In your case `T` is your buf's type which is `&'static str`, it [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#synthetic-implementations) Send and `A` is the implementation of `AsyncWrite`.

In this definition there is no proclamation that states `w` is a `Send` (or it has a `'static`/**owned** lifetime) :

```rust
pub fn say_hello(w: Box<dyn tokio::io::AsyncWrite>)
```

that's why tokio run is not accepting `WriteAll` Future.